# Unable to install nuget pagckage Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, asp.net-identity

I'm unable to install **nuget** pagckage

**Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.**

When I run the install -package cmd I recieve the following message. It states I'm trying to install the package into a project with .NET 4 but the package 0doesn't reference that. Using VS2010 .NET v4

Thank you in advance.

Below is PM> Text:

> PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core Installing
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'. You are downloading
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core from Microsoft, the license agreement
>   to which is available at
>   http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm.
>   Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with
>   their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and
>   dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements.
>   If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the
>   relevant components from your device. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'. Adding
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0' to PracticeMvcApplication.
>   Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'. Successfully
>   uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'. Install failed.
>   Rolling back... Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.1.0'. You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but
>   the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
>   that are  compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

Comment: I believe that Asp.net Identity is part of .NET 4.5.1, I don't think it can be used in a project that targets .NET 4.0

Comment: Andrew is correct, and the error message tells you that exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Andrew is correct, you can't install Identity on a project that targets .Net 4 or lower

Comment: did you mean to say 4.5.1 and not lower?

Comment: Therefore we cannot use ASP.NET Identity with Visual Studio 2010 or lower. Thank you everyone for your assistance.